# Let $n\geq 1$ and B a group of elements $(i _1,i_2,…,i_n)$ so $i_j \in \{-1,1\}$. Let’s assume $ |B|>\frac{2^{n+1}}{n}$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $n\geq 1$ and B a group of elements $(i _1,i_2,…,i_n)$ so  $i_j \in \{-1,1\}$. Let’s assume $ |B|>\dfrac{2^{n+1}}{n}$. Show that exists 3 diffrent elements in B so every 2 of them differ from each other in exactly 2 coordinates( 3 points in B are vertexes of a Equilateral triangle with length √8)

Tried to solve with pigeon hole principle but it doesn't really work.I really not sure what to even try to use in the question. If someone have any leads how to try and solve it will be really helpful

Comment: Please use MathJax in future. I suggest you [edit] the question too.

Comment: @IdanDaniel can you explain < מ+! > or rewrite it? And please check if $(מ+!)/n$ is the right exponent. It was not clear to me.

Comment: sorry, i translated it from another language. edited it

Comment: The title still needs editing, @IdanDaniel.

Comment: now i edited the title too

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using double counting method and pigeonhole principle. Define for $v=(v_i)_{i=1}^n$ and $ w=(w_i)_{i=1}^n$ in $V:=\{-1,1\}^n$,
$$
d(v,w) = |\{i \;|\;v_i \neq w_i\}|.
$$  That is, $d(v,w)$ is the number of coordinates $i$ such that $v_i \neq w_i$. We will show there exist $v\in V$ and distinct $w_i \in B$, $i=1,2,3$ such that $d(v,w_i) = 1$ for $i=1,2,3$. Then it follows $d(w_i, w_j) = 2$ for all $i\neq j$ as we wanted.

**Proof**: Let us define $$X= \{(v,w)\in V\times B\;|\;d(v,w) =1\}.
$$ We will count $|X|$ using double counting method. First, note that
$$
|X| = \sum_{(v,w)\in X}1 = \sum_{v\in V} |\{w\in B\;|\; d(v,w) = 1\}|.
$$ On the other hand, we have
$$
|X| = \sum_{w \in B} |\{v\in V \;|\; d(v,w) =1\}| =\sum_{w \in B} n = n|B|>2^{n+1}.
$$ Since $|V| = 2^n$, this gives us
$$
\frac{1}{|V|}\sum_{v\in V} |\{w\in B\;|\; d(v,w) = 1\}|>2.
$$ By pigeonhole principle, it follows that there exists $v\in V$ such that
$$
 |\{w\in B\;|\; d(v,w) = 1\}|\ge 3.
$$ Thus, there exist distinct $w_i, i=1,2,3$ in $B$ such that $d(v,w_i) = 1$. This proves the claim.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed proof! it exactly what i needed

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: For each $w$, $v$ for which $d(v,w)=1$ is obtained by changing sign of $j$-th coordinate  $w_j$ of $w$ and leaving the rest. We can take $j = 1,2,\ldots, n$. Thus there are exactly $n$ number of $v$'s for which $d(v,w)=1$.

Comment: got it, thanks!